# How to get libboost-thread1.46 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Folks,

Our application is distributed in binary form to many of our customers. The application was compiled on Ubuntu 12.04 and is dependent on libboost-thread1.46.1, among other things.

All of our customers also have Ubuntu 12.04 on their servers and our application worked just fine.

As some customers have indicated that they might use Ubuntu 12.10 in future, we built a new box with Ubuntu 12.10 and tried to install the needed dependencies. However, libboost-thread1.46 is no longer found in Ubuntu standard repositories. The version that seems to be available is libboost-thread.49 and libboost.thread.50.

I am wondering if there is a way to install libboost.thread1.46 on Ubuntu 12.10. This would obviate the need for recompiling the application.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Only manually from boost sources, or you can try link boost_thread statically, but why you don't want to use boost_thread1.49?

Comment: Hi ForEveR. We are trying to avoid creating and managing two different applications for 12.04 vs 12.10.